# Default render output folder

Tags: rendering

I rendered an intro template and I don't want to have to render it again. If I didn't select an output folder, where would the file end up?

Comment: For me it was by default "/tmp/" on my linux machine.

Answer (score 4):

If I remember correctly the default output is C:\tmp folder.

The files save to the path set in the Preferences window

[image]

For 2.8 check here:

[image]

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/31180)

Comment: @ShadyPuck By default, the files go into "C:\tmp", even though the answer is not very detailed or convincing, it is an acceptable answer and might just be exactly what BrocolliForest wanted to hear. It definitely doesn't require clarification from the asker.

Comment: I tried but i don't think it went to the default folder so i don't know where it would've went so i think i'll just render it again